# Missing Entity- DIH - Solr4.8.1 Tomcat 7

Tags: mysql, tomcat, solr, tomcat7, dataimporthandler

I have solr 4.8.1 running on Tomcat7, on my  CentOS Linux vps. I set up my data import handler similar to the one I have running locally but clicking the execute button does nothing. Logging is not showing up in the Admin interface but I think its happening in catalina.err and catalina.out. In those files I do not see any errors from solr. Below is my setup for the DIH.

In solr config:

```
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
<lib path="/opt/solr.4.8.1/example/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar" />
...
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">      
   <lst name="defaults">        
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>      
   </lst>       
</requestHandler>
```

In data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/giftsth_gtw" 
              user="giftsth_solr" 
              password="mypassword"/>
  <document>
    <entity name="id" query="select id,price,title,description,main_image,alt_images,retailer,link,gender,age,type,category,creation_date from solr_listings">
      <field column="category" name="category" splitBy=","></field>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

EDIT: I narrowed down the problem to a missing entity error. In chrome debugger the javascript error shows that it won't call the import because there is no entity yet in my config file their is an entity. Its the same exact setup as my local version yet there is no entity under the tab.

Comment: Have a look at https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging to set up proper logging for Solr, as it doesn't provide much to the default logs for Tomcat without setting up logging first. There is also a LogTransformer (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#LogTransformer) in DIH for providing more debug information while attempting to import.

Comment: I got the logging up and running but it won't execute. In chrome debugger I get a java script error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null for the entity element.

Comment: When do you get the javascript error? When you try to start the import?

Comment: When I click the execute button under the solr admin panel. I know you can use the url but when I did that I think I got an infinite loop.